# Есть ли жизнь Xamarin в Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, windows-8

Что ни делаю, не могу настроить визуальный редактор.
При попытке редактировать Main.axml
Сперва требовало обновления пакетов Android SDK. Обновления проделывал поэтапно ибо версии не перескакивает.
Теперь все равно появляется следующая ошибка.

```
        System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException: Не найдены операции экспорта, соответствующие ограничению: 
        ContractName    VisualStudioWorkspace
        RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace
       в System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
       в System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore(Type type, Type metadataViewType, String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
       в System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueCore[T](String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
       в Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerInterface.GetCodeModelBridge() в c:\data\lanes\3513\680125b0\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerInterface.cs:строка 154
       в Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.get_CodeModelBridge()
       в Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.<UpdateDesignerResourceIds>d__175.MoveNext()
    --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
       в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       в Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.<EnsureLoaded>d__139.MoveNext()
    --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
       в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       в Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidRenderSession.<InitSession>

d__105.MoveNext()
```

Может кто то побеждал это?
Win 8.1 Pro

Comment: Нет возможности обновиться до 17 или 19-ой версии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вариант смены версии Visual Studio вам не подходит или не помогает.

Как обходной вариант для верстки это использование плагина XamarIDEA, который открывает .axml страницу в Android Studio (Создает синхронизированный проект со всеми ресурсами). 
[Примеры и исходный код](https://github.com/EgorBo/Xamaridea),  [Visual Studio Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EgorBogatov.XamarIDEA)